# Displaying all leafs in binary tree using array implementation

Tags: c++, arrays, binary-tree

I am writing a binary tree using the array implementation, and for my last function `displayLeafValues()` I am trying to only display the leafs. The way I have it right now, it will output the index value of 70 then the leaf values.

Output for last function:
70
25
62
90
120

Desired output:
25
62
90
120

I tried indexing it from 25 but I get a endless loop when I try to display the other values. I was wondering if anyone could give me some suggestion. Thank y'all.

```
class BinaryTree{
public:
int sizeOfArray;
int* binaryArray;

void insertElement(int x);
void searchElement(int x);
void parent(int x);
int extendSize(int x);
void preOrder(int index);
void postOrder(int index);
void displayRSR(int index);
void displayLSR(int index);
int treeLeafsCount(int index);
void displayLeafValues(int index);

BinaryTree(int sizeOfArray){
    int newSize = extendSize(sizeOfArray);
    binaryArray = new int[newSize];

    for(int x = 0; x < sizeOfArray; x++){
        binaryArray[x] = NULL;
    }
 }
};

int BinaryTree::extendSize(int x){
int value = 0;
for(int y = 0; y<x +1; y++){
    value =(2*value) +2;
 }
  return value;
}
void BinaryTree::insertElement(int x){
  int currentIndex = 0;
  std::cout <<"Adding "<< x;
  while(true){
     if(binaryArray[currentIndex] ==NULL){
         binaryArray[currentIndex] = x;
         std::cout << "Inserted at index: " << currentIndex <<std::endl;
         break;
      }
      else if(binaryArray[currentIndex] <=x){
          if(binaryArray[currentIndex] ==x){
             std::cout << "ERROR! --Repeating element" << std::endl;
             break;
          }
          else{
              std::cout<<" Right ";
              currentIndex = (2* currentIndex +2);
          }
      }
      else if(binaryArray[currentIndex] >= x){
             if(binaryArray[currentIndex] ==x){
                 std::cout << "ERROR! -- Repeating element"<<std::endl;
                 break;
              }
              else{
                 std::cout <<" Left ";
                 currentIndex = (2*currentIndex +1);
         }
      }
   }
}
void BinaryTree::searchElement(int x){
   int currentIndex = 0;
   while(true){
      if(binaryArray[currentIndex] == NULL){
      std::cout << "Not Found" << std::endl;
      break;
      }
      if(binaryArray[currentIndex] == x){
      std::cout << "Found at index: " <<currentIndex <<std::endl;
      break;
      }else if(binaryArray[currentIndex] < x){
      currentIndex = (2* currentIndex +2);
      }else if(binaryArray[currentIndex > x]){
      currentIndex = (2* currentIndex +1);
       }
     }
  }
 void BinaryTree::parent(int x){
  while(x !=0){
      x = (x-1)/2;
     }
  }
  void BinaryTree::preOrder(int index){
     if(binaryArray[index] !=NULL){
     std::cout << binaryArray[index] << " " << std::endl;
     preOrder(2* index +1);
     preOrder(2 * index +2);
     }
    }
   void BinaryTree::postOrder(int index){
      if(binaryArray[index] !=NULL){
        postOrder(2 * index +1);
        postOrder(2 * index +2);
        std::cout << binaryArray[index] << " " << std::endl;
      }
     }
  void BinaryTree::displayRSR(int index){
    if(binaryArray[index] !=NULL){
       std::cout << binaryArray[index] << " " << std::endl;
       displayRSR(2 * index +2);
      }
     }
  void BinaryTree::displayLSR(int index){
     if(binaryArray[index] !=NULL){
     std::cout << binaryArray[index]<< " " << std::endl;
     displayLSR(2 * index +1);
    }
  }
int BinaryTree::treeLeafsCount(int index){
   if(binaryArray[index] ==NULL){
       return 1;
    }
  else{
     return treeLeafsCount(2*index+1) + treeLeafsCount(2*index+2);
     }
   }
void BinaryTree::displayLeafValues(int index){
    if(binaryArray[index] !=NULL){
    std::cout << binaryArray[index]<< " " << std::endl;
        displayLeafValues(index+16); //Does work but I still get the 70
        displayLeafValues(index+21);
        displayLeafValues(index+12);
        displayLeafValues(index+14);
  }
 }
int main(){

BinaryTree tree(13);

tree.insertElement(70);
tree.insertElement(50);
tree.insertElement(100);
tree.insertElement(30);
tree.insertElement(60);
tree.insertElement(80);
tree.insertElement(110);
tree.insertElement(20);
tree.insertElement(68);
tree.insertElement(90);
tree.insertElement(120);
tree.insertElement(25);
tree.insertElement(62);

std::cout <<"Building BST is completed. \n\n";
std::cout <<"Values of the Binary Search tree. \n\n";

//Pre-Order Traversal
std::cout <<"Pre-Order Traversal of the BST : \n\n";
tree.preOrder(0);

//Post-Order Traversal
std::cout << "Post-Order Traversal of the BST :\n\n";
tree.postOrder(0);

//All right sub root values
std::cout<<"Here are all right sub root values for the BST :\n\n";
tree.displayRSR(2);

//All left sub root values
std::cout<<"Here are all left sub root values for the BST :\n\n";
tree.displayLSR(1);

//Counting Number of Leafs .
std::cout<<"\n\nNumber of Leafs =   " <<tree.treeLeafsCount(3);

//Display the leaf values
std::cout<<"\n\nHere are the leaf values in the BST:\n\n";
tree.displayLeafValues(0);
}
```

Comment: Probably unrelated, but why are you comparing an `int` with `NULL` in `if (binaryArray[currentIndex] == NULL)` and elsewhere? Seems an odd choice.

Comment: Ah. Probably because you assign it `NULL` here: `binaryArray[x] = NULL;` Still seems odd. Why `NULL` and not 0?

Comment: I would expect `insertElement` to call `extendSize` at some point. It doesn't and there are no bounds checks, so odds are good that you overflow at some point.  Can't do much beyond guess what happens at that point.

Comment: It was just the way I was shown how to do it. I just ran it with 0 out of curiosity and it runs.

Comment: Just ran it myself. Program went out of bounds inserting 120. Tried to insert into index 14 of a 13 element array.

Comment: that is not how you traverse leaves. why did you hardcode the indices?

Comment: I added 55 and 200 to the array and it was able to index it for 14 and15. I'm still using 'NULL'.

Comment: To be honest it was the only way, I could figure out how to get to 25,62,90,120

Comment: Important note: Nothing in C++ will prevent you from marching out of the bounds of an array. Sometimes the program will crash, but this is not guaranteed. It appears you are getting by with dumb luck, but dumb luck makes for an unreliable program. Don't write out of bounds because you don't know what will happen.

Comment: No, I have to roll some of that back. Misinterpreted what you were doing with `extendSize`. Array is much bigger than 13. This means the program crashing at 120 is unrelated to array size. Diving in with the debugger.

Comment: There we go. `sizeOfArray` is 13, but it's not really the size of the array. That's `newSize`. However, you only initialize the array up to `sizeOfArray`, leaving the bulk of the array uninitialized. Chaos ensues as for `currentIndex` 13 or higher the value of `binaryArray[currentIndex]` is undefined. I fix that and then I get your results.

Comment: That's makes sense. Thank you, I went in and change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer I just needed to do this

```
  if(!binaryArray[2*index+1] && !binaryArray[2*index+2]){
    std::cout<<binaryArray[index] << " " << std::endl;
   }
  if(binaryArray[2*index+1]){
        displayLeafValues(2*index+1);
   }
  if(binaryArray[2*index+2]){
    displayLeafValues(2*index+2);
   }
```